# react native: _this2.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have function that works when a button is clicked. 
The function was working well before I add the setInterval method, after I added it, it shows the error : _this2.setState is not a function

here's the function :

```
 getWifiNetworksOnPress() {
   setInterval(function timer() {
   console.log("hello world");
   wifi.loadWifiList(
     wifiStringList => {
       console.log(wifiStringList);
       var wifiArray = JSON.parse(wifiStringList);
       this.setState({
         wifiList: wifiArray
       });
     },
     error => {
       console.log(error);
     }
   );
  }, 3000);
}
```

and here's the button :

```
<Button onPress={this.getWifiNetworksOnPress.bind(this)}>
  get location
</Button>
```

all the answers I found for this problem was adding .bind(this) to the onPress, but it didn't work. any idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a reference to the class using a const `_this` like the following code:

```
getWifiNetworksOnPress() {
   const this_ = this;
   setInterval(function timer() {
     console.log("hello world");
     wifi.loadWifiList(
       wifiStringList => {
         console.log(wifiStringList);
         var wifiArray = JSON.parse(wifiStringList);
         this_.setState({
           wifiList: wifiArray
         });
       },
       error => {
         console.log(error);
       }
     );
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this : https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback. In that case you should use arrow function (or bind) @MuhammadLebda

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a fat-arrow function inside the setInterval function?
This should work:

```
getWifiNetworksOnPress = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log("hello world");
        wifi.loadWifiList(wifiStringList => {
            console.log(wifiStringList);
            var wifiArray = JSON.parse(wifiStringList);
            this.setState({
                wifiList: wifiArray
            });
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

And

```
<Button onPress={this.getWifiNetworksOnPress}>
    Search Networks
</Button>
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer that the valid one. When you have a normal function, this refers to the function. Transforming it to an arrow function allows the use of this that now refers to the object.

Comment: @DavidAlvarez :) I agree with you.